# knockout - pass child array with viewmodel data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a viewModel like the following:

```js
var viewModel = new function () {

    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable();
     self.currentOrder = {

      orderId: ko.observable(),
      firstCropId: ko.observable(),
      secondCropId: ko.observable(),

      productDataList: ko.observableArray()
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to pass viewModel.currentOrder to the MVC controller like as follows:

```js
self.SaveOrder = function () {
      var url = '@Url.Action("SaveOrder", "Orders")';
      $.mobile.loading('show');

      var productInfo = {};

      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        productInfo = { Id: i, Rate: i + 11, Variable: i + 111 };
        viewModel.currentOrder.productDataList.push(productInfo);
      }


       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          dataType: 'json',
          data: viewModel.currentOrder,
          traditional: true,
          success: function (data, status) {

            //success
          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
          }

        });

    }; //Save
```

The controller method looks like this:

```
public Function SaveOrder(vm As OrdersModels.EditViewModel) As JsonResult

  Dim o As Sales.Order = GetCurrentOrder(vm.OrderId)

  With o
    .FirstCrop = vm.FirstCropId
    .SecondCrop = vm.SecondCropId
    .PreviousCrop = vm.PreviousFirstCropId

    'code to save order
 End function
```

OrdersModels.EditViewModel looks like this:

```
Public Class EditViewModel
   Public Property OrderId As Guid
   Public Property FirstCropId As Integer
   Public Property SecondCropId As Integer

   Public Property ProductDataList As List(Of OrderProducts)
End Class

Public Class OrderProducts
  Public Property Id As Integer
  Public Property Rate As Decimal
  Public Property Variable As Decimal
End Class
```

The controller is getting all data except vm.ProductDataList is nothing. I tried all sorts of things like passing JSON.stringify(viewModel.currentOrder) as data, adding contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' without luck.

How to pass the data to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: url,
       contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       dataType: 'json',
       data:ko.toJSON(self.currentOrder),
       success: function (data, status) {
                   //success
       },
       error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          $.mobile.loading('hide');
       }

});
```